# Get path to first called/started module by node command

Tags: node.js, path

How to get path to directory where 'first called module' is?

For example we have bash file called `startnode.sh` in `/bin/` folder

```
node ~/path/to/file/index.js
```

now in index.js we have complex code with requiring other files like:

```
var myMoudle = require("./module.js");
```

etc. Now we are in random folder: `/qpa/dir/` then going to start our node process by bash file:

```
startnode
```

and in our `module.js` we going to get working directory:

```
console.log(process.cwd());
```

suprise! `process.cwd()` return `/qpa/dir/` instead of `~/path/to/file/`

why?

I need the directory where node process begin, directory to first called module.

Comment: Sorry i didn't understand correctly what you needed at the first time that i read.

Answer (score 0):

Use env variables:

consider following structure:

```
test
├── bin.sh
└── test
    └── hello.js
```

in bin.sh:

```
DIR="$( cd "$( dirname "${BASH_SOURCE[0]}" )" && pwd )" node BASE_PATH/test/test/hello.js
```

in hello.js:

```
console.log(__dirname); // BASE_PATH/test/test
console.log(process.env.DIR); // BASE_PATH/test
console.log(process.cwd()); // BASE_PATH
```

note: you need to replace BASE_PATH with your path (~/path/to/file/)